# Running same exe file from different consoles using different parameters

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, cmd.exe

I have a C++ exe that reads images and writes text files based on some algorithms. Since it takes different parameters as input, I can run multiple instances of the same exe without overwriting the data at output. My question is: Would running the same exe from different console windows result in letting the exe share memory space? Or, can I completely rely on Windows doing a good job at separating the memory spaces of the two instances of the program? Appreciate your inputs and suggestions.

Comment: So, running the exe from different consoles with different parameters wouldn't trouble the results, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken that it how Windows works by default, the two processes are completely isolated from each other despite being the same exe. For example if you pull up the `Windows Task Manager` when running Chrome you'll see a bunch of `chrome.exe`s all over the place, all running the same executable but with different options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, are the memory spaces shared? I load a number of images into the memory using one exe and the same images using the same exe but with different options. The second exe loads the images in not time while the first exe takes normal time to load the images.

Comment: It think what you are seeing there is the system caching the file into memory the first time you load it, so the second time the other application needs it, it's already in memory.

Comment: I did not know the OS was intelligent enough to load from the same memory space. I thought this has to be done explicitly by the application developer to make applications share the memory space. Learnt something new; I'll read up more on this. Thanks for the answer.